# Number of records having fewer images in mysql select

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I have two table having images for listings.I want to get number of listing having fewer than three images. Here is my query but it is not working correctly.

```
select 
    @table1_pic:=(select 
            count(i.id)
        from
            crm_rentals_images as i,
            crm_rentals as r
        where
            r.id = i.rentals_id and r.status = 2
                and r.is_archive = 0
                and r.is_active = 1
        group by i.rentals_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) < 3) as pic_rentals,
    @table2_pic:=(select 
            count(i.id)
        from
            crm_sales_images as i,
            crm_sales as r
        where
            r.id = i.rentals_id and r.status = 2
                and r.is_archive = 0
                and r.is_active = 1
        group by i.rentals_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) < 3) as ppic_sales,
    (@table1_pic + @table2_pic) as tot_img
```

This give me error

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Note:I want to get total number of each and then SUM of both

Comment: the error exactly explains the problem. your subqueries return more than 1 row which is forbidden for one field to hold multiple values. you are using group by on one field (which is not unique) and count on other thats why you are having more than one row.

Comment: How i can SUM them?I think i need to SUM each one again?

Comment: no sum would give the same error cause you are using group by on a field where different values are stored. run the subqueries first and make sure they only have 1 row as a result.

Comment: what you are trying to do is summing
1,1,2,1,4,2,3
and
2,4,6,3,5,3,5,3,5
you can first sum the subqueries. but if you are going to sum them, why group by in the first place?